# How can I use IDataErrorInfo with mvvmcross and monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, inotifydataerrorinfo

I am trying to build a cross platform application.  Currently I am setting up a project using Xamarin MonoDroid 4.7 and MVVMCross.  I would like to be able to use INotifyDataErrorInfo but I get the following compilation error:

The type 'System.ComponentModel.INotifyDataErrorInfo' exists in both 'c:\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll' and 'c:\Users\MvvmCross.PortableSupport.3.0.6\lib\MonoAndroid16\System.Windows.dll

Has anyone come across this/developed a workaround or solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *think* Mono for Android/Xamarin.Android has recently added this support - but the situation isn't clear - see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5340

When we get this confirmed and work out which versions do/don't have this - which is hopefully in the coming week or two - then MvvmCross will hopefully be able to remove its version.

Also, I **hope** but I don't know that the MvvmCross versions of `System.Windows`, `System.Net`, etc can be removed in the near future - see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8035

This is not at all clear at present, and it's likely to be a source of issues while PCL support from Xamarin moves through none->alpha->beta->stable

I'm afraid those 'NEW' bugzilla issues above represent all the information I have on this at present.

---

In the meantime... if you need to resolve the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` within your own project and environment, then one route forwards is to branch the MvvmCross source and to change the MvvmCross shim `System.Windows.dll` to type forward instead of replacing this type - the code is in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/PortableSupport/System.Windows

I am sorry about these problems... and I'm very much looking forwards to having official PCL support from Xamarin so I no longer have to work around them.

Comment: Just checked - and `DataErrorsChangedEventArgs` definitely isn't in Xamdroid 4.6.04 which is the stable I'm running and releasing from at present.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response, as well as all the other support you provide!

Comment: Does XF care about `INotifyDataErrorInfo` at all?